# WS.URL in Play Application Test

Tags: playframework

I created a dummy POST endpoint in a clean play project.

In my Application Test, if I use POST("/"), it works.
If I use

```
    WSRequest postRequest = WS.url("http://10.0.1.105:9000/");
    response = postRequest.post();
```

The POST always timeout in 60 seconds... anyone having the similar issue ?

Comment: Can you post your routes file?

Comment: it would suggest that 10.0.1.105 may be an issue resolving...what happens if you replace with localhost or 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1):

In dev mode your thread pool is 1. Your test is using this thread so there is no more thread in the pool to serve the WS call.

Add this to your application.conf to add another thread in your pool in test mode

```
%test.play.pool=2
```